# Print permutations of a string given an index

Tags: go, recursion

I'm trying to learn recursion and going through the Stanford online video lectures and textbook. In the programming exercises a question is posed to generate all permutations for a string given an index. For example `"ABCD"` and index 2. This should generate `"ABCD"` and `"ABDC"`.

I understand how to generate the permutations by using `func permute(prefix, suffix)` but this question is confusing me. Here is want I have so far:

```golang
func permute(s string) {
    permuteHelper(s, 2)
}

func permuteHelper(s string, idx int) {
    if idx == 0 {
        fmt.Println(s)
        return
    }
    for i := idx; i < len(s); i++ {
        newS := s[:idx]
        suffix := s[idx : idx+1]
        newS += suffix
        permuteHelper(newS, idx-1)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
AB
AB
AB
AB
```

I don't want the answer, but perhaps some guidance in my thought process. I know I should create a static `"AB"` and then select `"C"` on one iteration and then select `"D"`, then my base case should be triggered and print the string. Control will then return to `"AB"` and `"i"` should be 3 and I choose `"D"`, but how do I then chose `"C"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track and the overall form looks fine, but the details are still blurry.

Firstly,

```
newS := s[:idx]
suffix := s[idx : idx+1]
newS += suffix
```

is equivalent to

```
newS := s[:idx+1]
```

No real permuting is going on here; this is chopping off the back of the string and ignoring the loop variable `i` entirely. Try to swap two characters in the string for each recursive call and use both `i` and `idx` to do so; think of `idx` as a fixed pivot for swapping every `i...len(s)` element with per call frame. Good job ensuring you're not reassigning to the string in the current scope, though, because that'd mess up state for later iterations of the loop.

Second suggestion: To establish the base case, count recursively up to `len(s)` instead of down to zero. You can pretty much pretend the entire first chunk of the array doesn't exist. Think of it just like a regular permutation algorithm except you've skipped the first `idx` indices.

Also, this is more of a design point than an algorithmic issue, but I would expose the `idx` parameter to the caller instead of hiding it behind a wrapper. This makes the function reusable and more obvious as to what it does--as a user of a library, I'd be perplexed if a function named `permute` refused to permute the first 2 chars.

It's better to return a result than produce a [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) like printing, but I'll set that aside for pedagogy's sake.

Here's one solution (spoiler alert!):

> ```
> package main
>  
> import "fmt"
>  
> func permute(s string, idx int) {
>     if idx == len(s) {
>         fmt.Println(s)
>     }
>  
>     for i := idx; i < len(s); i++ {
>         a := []rune(s)
>         a[i], a[idx] = a[idx], a[i]
>         permute(string(a), idx + 1)
>     }
> }
>  
> func main() {
>     permute("abcde", 2)
> }
> ```

`permute("abcde", 2)` produces

```
abcde
abced
abdce
abdec
abedc
abecd
```

Comment: `s[:i] --> "ABD"  s[i+1:] --> "C" s[i:i+1] --> "E"` stepping thru with a debugger console was key. I see that you keep increasing the "prefix" `s[:i]`, then you get the chars *after* the current index `s[i+1:]` and finally the index. thank you. how did you develop intuition to solve (or derive, not memorize) these types of problems?

Comment: I think I just memorized the basic permutations algorithm, more or less. I doubt I could derive many classic algorithms on my own. Having said that, after seeing a number of algorithms it's become a bit easier to recognize common patterns and adapt them as needed.